# How to use Ngmodel in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to save text to text file from text area by using a blob.

in .html

```
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
<form action="textarea1" method="post" name="test">
<br /><br/>
<textarea type = "Text" #box2 [(ngModel)]= "textareabox" placeholder="type something here.." (keyup) = "getData(box2.value)" style="width: 500px;height: 700px;" ></textarea>

<br /><br/>

<button (click)="saveAsTextFile()"  type="submit" style="width: 100px;height:30px" >Send</button>

</form>
```

in .ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Important Event in Angular';
  getData(val:any) {
    console.warn(val);
  }
    textareabox ="";
    txtData:any = this.textareabox;
 
    constructor() { }
    
    saveAsTextFile(){
    
      var data = new Blob([this.txtData], {type: 'text/plain'});
 
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
 
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      document.body.appendChild(a);
 
      a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'Essay.txt';
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      a.remove();
    }
}
```

*** I use ngmodel in textarea but I can't save text that I type in Textarea. ***
** Updated **

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sJqP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The "txtData" variable equals an empty string.
You should use "textareabox" in the "saveAsTextFile" function:

```
saveAsTextFile(){
    
      var data = new Blob([this.textareabox], {type: 'text/plain'});
      ...
```

Comment: I have tried use textareabox in the saveAsTextFile function but I still cannot save text from textarea to text file. I added picture in updated post.